# Unable to mark task as not completed using Java libraries for Google Tasks API's

Tags: google-api-java-client

I'm trying to set up a method to change the status of a task. The code I'm running is this:

```
private void changeStatus(String taskId, String listId, String newStatus) throws IOException {
    Task task = mService.tasks().get(listId,taskId).execute();
    task.setStatus(newStatus);
    mService.tasks().update(listId, task.getId(), task).execute();
}
```

I'm passing the task id, list id and newStatus (which is either "completed" or "needsAction"). The code works fine for marking a task as completed, but it gives me an "invalid value" error when I try to mark it as not completed.

I've tried instead of setting the status to "needsAction", setting the completed date like so:

```
task.setCompleted(new DateTime(new Date().getTime()));
```

But that doesn't work either.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've solved it. 

The problem was that I needed to set the completed field to null first. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what should be done:

```
private void changeStatus(String taskId, String listId, String newStatus) throws IOException {
    Task task = mService.tasks().get(listId,taskId).execute();
    task.setCompleted(null);
    task.setStatus(newStatus);
    mService.tasks().update(listId, task.getId(), task).execute();
}
```